# tex programming

Tags: latex, tex

can some one help m from where and how i will i learn the tex programming
because i have to make package which i will use in miktex

Comment: Hello Welcome to StackOveflow and for showing interest and learning from the community but this question is too broad for stackoverflow, stackoverflow is a place to ask question with respect to the specific problems and too broad question are generally not allowed, also have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

If you are really determined, the book by the original author of TeX itself is a great source: http://www.ctex.org/documents/shredder/src/texbook.pdf . (I wonder if this is a legal copy but found as the first hit on Google.)

Answer (score 0):

Package writing is generally where the most arcane features of the TeX language are most heavily exercised. Writing a package should *not* be the first thing you do with (La)TeX!

Writing this in 2018, I would suggest that you start with learning XeLaTeX and the `fontspec` package. That can save you a whole bunch of grief w.r.t. text encodings and fonts.

If you have specific questions, head over to https://tex.stackexchange.com/.